# Why does adding a character class to the end of a regex fail to match hex numbers?

Tags: regex, perl

Perl accepts:

```
my @resultado = $texto =~ /[^g-zG-z]$RE{num}{real}{-base=>16}/g
```

but doesn't accept:

```
my @resultado = $texto =~ /[^g-zG-z]$RE{num}{real}{-base=>16}[^g-zG-z]/g
```

I just add `[^g-zG-z]` at the end; at the beginning it works but not at the end. Why? 
I want to print hexadecimal numbers but, for example, in cases where there is a word like 'call' it should not say that 'ca' is a hexadecimal number.

Comment: when it doesn't work? what is the input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  It would help a lot if you provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Note that your regex design would include both the `=` signs in `=123=` as part of your hex value.  Are you using [`Regexp::Common`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3A%3ACommon)?  If so, say so (but your SSCCE would render this question moot, of course).

Comment: yes, sorry, my english level is awful and I am starting with programation and internet, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The character class `[^g-zG-z]` matches a single character that is not in the range g through z. That is not what you want for matching a hexadecimal digit. For example, if your hex number occurs at the end of the string (that is, nothing follows it), the match will fail.

You did not provide sample data. A pattern such as

```
my @resultado = $texto =~ /\b([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\b/g;
```

may give you what you want. `\b` matches at a word **b**oundary, and that constrains the hex digits to occur within a single “word.”

In [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3A%3ACommon) terms, the above line is expressed as

```
my @resultado = $texto =~ /\b($RE{num}{int}{-base => 16})\b/g;
```

Comment: Sorry for my english and my bad description of the problem I am just a kid of foreign country. I have to use the module Regexp::Common so I have to solve this with something similar to $RE{num}{real}{-base=>16}

Comment: yes, it almosts works, I have this input .txt:
#numeros enteros
33
100
#numeros decimales
25.0
12.75
#numero hexa
ABC770
1010A
#no numeros 
don quijote de la mancha
from russia with love

And the output is almost good, the problem is for the number 12.0 it takes 12 and 0 as result, the result must be 12.0 not 12 and 0

Comment: ok I fix it, /\b($RE{num}{real}{-base => 16})\b/g instead of using int i used real and its works, thanks for all